# I can't figure out how to put PHP inside an echo

Tags: php, echo

Probably a question that has already been posted a hundred times, but I just can't figure it out.

```
<?php

try{

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT patient_id,voornaam,achternaam,leeftijd,lengte,gewicht,bmi_index FROM patienten ORDER BY patient_id DESC');
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {


   echo  '<div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="patient_wrapper">
                <a href=""><img src="../style/images/patient.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <p>'.$row['voornaam'].' '.$row['achternaam'].'</p>
            <p>
                <a href="javascript:delpost(\'<?php echo $row[\'patient_id\'];?>\')">Verwijder</a>
            </p>
        </div>';
}

} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

I need te line of javascript:delpost to work, but I just can't get it done. Anybody wanna help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a working example of how to do it 2 lines above....

Comment: PHP is not recursively embeddable. You're already doing string concatenation with the `$row['voornaam']` immediately before, so why are you doing the recursive embedding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a working example just two lines above it. You could do something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:delpost(\''.$row['patient_id'].'\')">Verwijder</a>
```

(inside the echo of course)